# Find most common combination of elements in several arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have several arrays, like:

```
var arr1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var arr2 = new[] { "A", "D" };
var arr3 = new[] { "A", "B", };
var arr4 = new[] { "C", "D" };
var arr5 = new[] { "B", "C", "D" };
var arr6 = new[] { "B", "A", };
```

... etc.

How can I get most common **combination** of elements in all of those arrays?

In this case it is A and B, because they occur in arr1, arr3 and arr6, and C and D, because they occur in arrays arr1, arr4 and arr5.

Just to mention that elements can be in any kind of collection, ie. in ArrayLists also.

**UPDATE** uuhhh, I was not clear enough...... Most common combinations of **two elements** in an array. That's what I tried to show in example, but did not mention in my question.

Sorry 
:-((

Comment: Define most common.  Top N counts, existing at least Y times or what?

Comment: `"A"` by itself is common to arrays 1, 2, 3, and 6. Same goes for `"B"`, which appears in four, not three, arrays. Why do they need to be considered in combination with each other?

Comment: your problem is not complete.  You ask about most common elements, but your example is about pairs of elements.  Are only pairs of elements considered?  How many instances must exist for an element to be considered a candidate for "Most Common"? The single element "A" is in 4 arrays.

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the number of collections that you are planning to have?

Comment: Thanks for the update, that clears up a lot of confusion. See my updated answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure that each item appears only once in each array, you could just concatenate them together and get the counts, for example:

```
var arrs = new[] { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6 };
var intermediate = arrs.SelectMany(a => a)
                       .GroupBy(x => x)
                       .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
var maxCount = intermediate.First().Count;
var results = intermediate.TakeWhile(x => x.Count == maxCount);
```

Or if you prefer query syntax, that would be:

```
var arrs = new[] { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6 };
var intermediate = 
    from a in arrs.SelectMany(a => a)
    group a by a into g
    orderby g.Count() descending
    select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
var maxCount = intermediate.First().Count;
var results = intermediate.TakeWhile(x => x.Count == maxCount);
```

The result set will contain 3 items:

```
Key, Count
"A", 4 
"B", 4 
"D", 4
```

---

**Update**

Given your updated question, something like this should work:

```
var items = arrs.SelectMany(a => a).Distinct();
var pairs =
    from a in items
    from b in items
    where a.CompareTo(b) < 0
    select new { a, b };
var results = 
    (from arr in arrs
     from p in pairs 
     where arr.Contains(p.a) && arr.Contains(p.b)
     group arr by p into g
     orderby g.Count() descending
     select g.Key)
    .First();
```

The logic here is:

1. First find all distinct items in any array
2. Then find every pair of items to search for
3. Get of every pair, grouped by a list of what arrays contain that pair
4. Order by the groups by the number of arrays that contain each pair, descending
5. Return the first pair

Comment: Even if the items appear multiple times, you can use `SelectMany(a=>a.Distinct())` to overcome the problem. [I doubt that that is what the OP is after, though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981046/find-most-common-elements-in-several-arrays#comment29745297_19981046), because if he wanted what your query gives, he'd talk about `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"D"` appearing four times, instead of `"A","B"` appearing three times.

Answer (score 1):

use a Dictionary which will store an element as an index, and the occurrence count as a value. Iterate each list and count the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var arr2 = new[] { "A", "D" };
var arr3 = new[] { "A", "B", };
var arr4 = new[] { "C", "D" };
var arr5 = new[] { "B", "C", "D" };
var arr6 = new[] { "B", "A", };

var results = new List<IEnumerable<string>>() { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6 }
                                .Select(arr => arr.Distinct())
                                .SelectMany(s => s)
                                .GroupBy(s => s)
                                .Select(grp => new { Text = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() })
                                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Count)
                                .ToList();
```

Gives you {A, 4}, {B, 4}, {D, 4}, {C, 3}

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new IEnumerable<String>[] {arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6}
                .SelectMany(a => a)
                .GroupBy(s => s)
                .GroupBy(g => g.Count())
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .SelectMany(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear as you have not clearly defined what you are looking for.  In general, you could combine all the arrays into one large array and count the distinct elements.  By then ordering the elements you can do whatever you intend to do with the "most common".

```
static void Main()
{
    var arr1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    var arr2 = new[] { "A", "D" };
    var arr3 = new[] { "A", "B", };
    var arr4 = new[] { "C", "D" };
    var arr5 = new[] { "B", "C", "D" };
    var arr6 = new[] { "B", "A", };
    List<string> combined = Combine(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6);

    var ordered = combined.OrderBy(i => i);//sorted list will probably help other functions work more quickly such as distinct
    var distinct = ordered.Distinct();

    var counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (var element in distinct)
    {
        var count = ordered.Count(i => i == element);
        counts.Add(element, count);
    }

    var orderedCount = counts.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value);

    foreach (var count in orderedCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", count.Key, count.Value);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static List<string> Combine(string[] arr1, string[] arr2, string[] arr3, string[] arr4, string[] arr5, string[] arr6)
{
    List<string> combined = new List<string>();
    combined.AddRange(arr1);
    combined.AddRange(arr2);
    combined.AddRange(arr3);
    combined.AddRange(arr4);
    combined.AddRange(arr5);
    combined.AddRange(arr6);
    return combined;
}
```

> Outputs: A : 4, B : 4, D : 4, C : 3